# how to show edge length based on unique value in networkx & matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

[image]

```py
self.DG = nx.MultiDiGraph()

# I add nodes
self.DG.add_node(a, image=matplot_image)

# & update edges like so
self.DG.add_edge(a,b,transitions=1)
self.DG[a][b][0]['transitions'] += 1

# but I can't get the edge with ['transitions'] = 2 to display always 1/2 the length of edges with ['transitions'] = 1 with 
pos = nx.spring_layout(self.DG, weight="transitions", k=20) # or
pos = nx.spring_layout(self.DG, weight="transitions")
```

without `k=20` it looks like:

[image: https://imgur.com/I9KIBnx]

Note: I'm having trouble to install pygraphviz https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/338 so I would prefer a solution without it

Comment: It's displaying the number.  Are you asking "why isn't the line length proportional to the number"?

Comment: yes Tim Roberts

Comment: I think you haven't let the simulation go enough rounds.  It's clearly having an effect; there's only one inner edge that is out of whack, and that one started out very long.

Comment: I think the problem is I want the nodes to be more spread out like in the 1st picture but also have the correct edge length

Comment: The attractive force is computed incorrectly in the spring layout / FR implementation in networkx, specifically [this line](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/drawing/layout.py#L545). The sum should be only over off-diagonal entries; as it stands they are basically adding a very large number (1/0) to all attractive forces thus washing out any edges and edge weights. There are other errors / problems with the implementation, so I wouldn't use it. The implementation in `igraph` is correct (as far as I can tell).